# Vuejs не создает компонент с именем circle

Tags: vue.js

Создаю локальный список компонентов. Если вывожу компонент с именем circle то браузер пишет вот такую ошибку

> Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: circle

Если circle даю новое имя, например в circlea то всё хорошо работает.
Что за магия?

Вот код codepen.io/AndrewMoryakov/pen/Kvmbpm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Собственно, ответ в вопросе. Вольный перевод ошибки:

> Нельзя использовать встроенные или зарезервированные названия HTML элементов в качестве идентификатора компонента

Списки зарезервированных названий, которые нельзя использовать для идентификатора компонента в *vue.js 2.4.2*

*HTML*

> html,body,base,head,link,meta,style,title,
>    address,article,aside,footer,header,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hgroup,nav,section,
>    div,dd,dl,dt,figcaption,figure,picture,hr,img,li,main,ol,p,pre,ul,
>    a,b,abbr,bdi,bdo,br,cite,code,data,dfn,em,i,kbd,mark,q,rp,rt,rtc,ruby,
>    s,samp,small,span,strong,sub,sup,time,u,var,wbr,area,audio,map,track,video,
>    embed,object,param,source,canvas,script,noscript,del,ins,
>    caption,col,colgroup,table,thead,tbody,td,th,tr
>    button,datalist,fieldset,form,input,label,legend,meter,optgroup,option
>    output,progress,select,textarea
>    details,dialog,menu,menuitem,summary
>    content,element,shadow,template,blockquote,iframe,tfoot

*SVG*

> svg,animate,circle,clippath,cursor,defs,desc,ellipse,filter,font-face
>    foreignObject,g,glyph,image,line,marker,mask,missing-glyph,path,pattern
>    polygon,polyline,rect,switch,symbol,text,textpath,tspan,use,view